# Custom theme/library based on MUI isues

Tags: css, reactjs, responsive-design, material-ui

The company wants to use the same UX/UI design in all our projects. So we purchased [MUI for Figma](https://material-ui.com/store/items/figma-react) design kit and UX/UI designer modified it.

Now we want to republish the MUI library with that design. The goal is that projects using our library will not depend on MUI and will have our design out of the box.

We have successfully created and published 2-3 components for PoC like this (simplified):

```
import { ThemeProvider } from '@emotion/react';
import MuiButton from '@mui/material/Button';
import * as React from 'react';
import theme from '../theme';

const Button = ({ style, ...other }) => (
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
        <MuiButton
            style={{
                textTransform: 'none',
                ...style,
            }}
            disableElevation
            {...other}
        />
    </ThemeProvider>
);

export default Button;
```

As you can see because we re-publish each component individually we have to wrap each one in a `ThemeProvider` and this can (or probably will) reduce performance.

Another problem is that some components in MUI are playing together, like `ButtonGroup` and `Button` and when you set attributes for the parent (like `color="primary"` it propagates them to the child (I've checked with source code). With our approach, each component behaves individually and you have to reapply the same attributes to the child.

How can we avoid these problems?

P.S. We're not bound to MUI and can choose another approach. Just don't want to deal with CSS cross-browser and accessibility issues.